# How to pass body payload to angular $resource DELETE call

Tags: angularjs, rest, angularjs-resource

I have standard angular $resource configured as such

```
angular.module('client.resources')

.factory('ProjectSubjectResource',['$resource',
    function ($resource) {
            release: {
                method: 'DELETE',
                isArray: false
            }
        });
    }]);
```

and I am calling this method as

```
ProjectSubjectResource.release({projectId: projectId, subjectId: 0},{ subjectIds: subjectIdArray})
```

where subjectIdArray is array of objects:

```
[{subject1: 213123}, {subject2: 3131}]
```

However, body of request does not contain that array. I suspect that DELETE request is the problem, as renaming method call to e.g. PUT makes difference.

Can I allow body of DELETE request somehow?

Comment: Looking on github at [$resource](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngResource/resource.js) it has `var hasBody = /^(POST|PUT|PATCH)$/i.test(action.method);` which looks like Angular doesn't include the body on `DELETE` requests intentionally... As to working round it, I don't know :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting on [Angular 1.6.4](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#164-phenomenal-footnote-2017-03-31), the `hasBody` action configuration was added.

You can now have:

```js
deleteSomething: {
    method: 'DELETE',
    hasBody: true
}
```

> **`hasBody`** - `{boolean}` - allows to specify if a request body should be
>   included or not. If not specified only POST, PUT and PATCH requests
>   will have a body.

[Reference](https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.4/docs/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299628/is-an-entity-body-allowed-for-an-http-delete-request).

The body of a request for a `DELETE` is ignored. You will have to use `POST` to do what you want, or describe the data you are sending with the URL.

**UPDATE**: `DELETE` requests can have a body since Angular 1.6.4; check [denisazevedo's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2056394/denisazevedo) answer for additional info.